# How to close the window with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Haven't been programming in JS for a while.
Now, I have following thing:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
   function enlarge()
   {
   window.close();
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="addresstomyimg.png" onClick="enlarge()" />
</body>
</html>
```

(it's very simplified, as, in fact, I have WordPress platform with custom JS modifications etc, but in general, this is the idea).

I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: Define "not working".  What do you expect to happen?  What is happening?

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=23c03746e3aa03f9&hl=en -> maybe that's why it's not working

Comment: Put `alert('enlarge')` in the top of the `enlarge()` function. Do you get the alert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript cant close the window unless it opened the window.

In your function, replace `window.close()` with `alert('here')` and you'll see the function works fine.

If you want your function to close a window, first open one:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup;

    function closewin()
    {
        popup.close();
    }
    function openwin()
    {
        popup = window.open('http://www.google.com');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="addresstomyimg.png" onclick="openwin()" /> Click to open, then come back here
    <br><br>
    <img src="addresstomyimg.png" onclick="closewin()" /> Click to close
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/pbFha/

Answer (score 6):

If you try running this script using Firefox and use the Firefox's Error Console to look for errors, you can see that the following error gets logged when you run this script.

```
Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.
```

You can launch the Error Console in Firefox by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

On Chrome, your script successfully closes the tab in which it is running.

Note that the right way to use the `<script>` tag while writing JavaScript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to close the main window, it won't work.

You can only close windows that were opened by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
   function enlarge()
   {
   self.close();
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="addresstomyimg.png" onClick="enlarge()" />
</body>
</html>
```